# Quartz | Cron expression not working as expected

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm trying to build up a cron expression that will trigger in every minute starting from a given hourly range.

My expression would be:

```
0 0/1 12/10-14 * 1-5 ?
```

I'm expecting this to work as, starting from 12.04 AM to 02.00PM trigger at every minute.

But when I start the application it just trigger from next minute of the hour 12.01 despite the range or starting minute at 12.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is mistake in your cron expression.

```
0 {start minute}/{every minute} [from hour- to hour] * 1-5 ?
```

So the answer is

It will start at 12:00 AM - 01 : 00 AM

```
0 4/1 0-1 * 1-5 ?
```

**It will start at 12:00 AM - 02 : 00 PM**

```
0 4/1 0-14 * 1-5 ?
```

It will start at 12:00 AM - 02 : 00 PM Every Day

```
0 4/1 0-14 * * ?
```

Comment: Cron works perfectly thanks. But when it misfires why it is going to the time in next hour instead of next day. Do I need to specify days also?

Comment: Can you specify which expression you are using from above?  For every day try (0 4/1 0-14 * * ?)

Comment: I'm using 0 4/1 0-1 * 1-5 ? . So lets say I will start the scheduler on 1PM, but instead of going to next day 12.04AM it goes to 1.04PM same day.

Comment: Have you unscheduled all previous scheduled jobs ? May you have already job but they are not unscheduled. Or try (0 4/1 0-1 * * ? )

Comment: Hi thanks again. It works fine now, I messed up a bit when defining the cron expression.

Answer (score 2):

Link provides you with the Quartz corn expressions
[Quarts scheduled expression documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)
The expression should be like

```
0 4/1 0-1 * 1-5 ?
```

to start a 12.04 AM and end at 2.00pm 
you can test your corn expression in this [Cornmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression

0 4/1 0-14 * * ?

It will start the job at 4th minute past 12:00 am and then execute every minute after that till 2:00 PM

```html
0 4/1 0-14 * * ?
   |   |  |   |
   |   |  |   |
   |   |  |   |--------till 2:00 pm
   |   |  |---------------------------12:00am
   |   |-------------------------------------------every minute
   |----------------------------------------------------------------Start at 4th Minute
```